# scipy sparse matrix multiplication is slow compared to numpy matrix multiplication

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I want to compute a [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix#:%7E:text=which%20simplifies%20to,are%20real%20numbers), which is the matrix product of the transpose of a matrix and itself (`X.T @ X`).

It happens that it is much fast to transform the matrix into a `numpy` array and then compute `X.T @ X` compared to performing directly the operation. I find this pretty surprising as transforming the matrix into a `numpy` array comes with the cost/drawback of converting the matrix into its dense representation.

Here is a small snippet to reproduce. It shows that `scipy` is 10 times slower.

```py
import time
from scipy import sparse

# generate random sparse matrix
n_samples, n_features = 10000, 200
density = 0.5
X = sparse.random(n_samples, n_features, density, format='csc')

# time scipy operation
start = time.time()
X.T @ X
duration_scipy = time.time() - start
print("scipy: ", duration_scipy)

# time numpy operations
start = time.time()
X_dense = X.toarray()
X_dense.T @ X_dense
duration_numpy = time.time() - start
print("numpy: ", duration_numpy)

print(
    "============\n"
    f"ratio np/sp: {duration_numpy / duration_scipy}"
)

# Output:
# scipy:  0.09316086769104004
# numpy:  0.009956836700439453
# ============
# ratio sp/np: 9.356472391169005
```

Is there an explanation for such a counter-intuitive behavior, as `scipy` takes advantage of the sparse nature of the data when computing the matrix product and thereby should be faster?

Comment: Sparse calculations have to track the indicies as well as values of the nonzero terms, so while there might be fewer multipiications, the time per multiplication is higher.  In my experience a sparse matrix needs to have a 5% or lower density (and be relatively large) to have time advantages.  Dense `matmul` is highly optimized, using BLAS like libraries where possible.

Comment: Look at your `X.T@X` - I get a density of 1 - every element of the (200,200) result is nonzero.  With that large of a sum-of-products dimension the sparse matrix has to be very sparse to get much sparsity in the result.

Comment: Numpy uses whatever optimized, threaded BLAS library it's linked to to call SYRK, which is a BLAS function optimized for calculating XTX. Scipy uses some C extensions for general matrix multiplications that were written a decade ago and aren't very well optimized (and are explicitly single-thread).